# Prove an improper integral is divergent

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Initial problem:Does this improper integral on an infinite interval converge?
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin{x}}{1+e^{-x}}dx
$$
**According to the answer it’s divergent** but I can’t prove it.

What I have thought of:

- $\vert\frac{\sin{x}}{1+e^{-x}}\vert$ is divergent. so methods for positive term integral won’t work.
- It’s non-negative on $[2kπ, 2kπ+π ] $ and non-positive on $[2kπ+π , 2kπ+2π ](k ∈ \mathbb{N} ) $.
  integral on the former interval is slightly larger than the latter one(absolute value). Might be able to estimate the integral on each $[2kπ, 2kπ+2π ] $?

*This is the first time I post a problem here. Somewhere might be inappropriate. I would really appreciate any help and answer.
*

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{{1 + e^{ - x} }} = 1 + O(e^{ - x} )$, so you have to consider the integral of $\sin x$ only.

Comment: @Anonymous how about functions where $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 2$ ? Or functions where the integral converges but the limit does not exist, such as $$f(x) = \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\sin^{-1}(\max\{\sin \pi x, 0\})\right)^{\left\lceil\frac{x}{2}\right\rceil^2-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sin x$ has  a positive lower bound on the interval $(2n\pi+\frac {\pi} 4, 2n\pi+\frac {3\pi} 4)$ (namely, $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$). Show that $\sum_n \int_{2n\pi+\frac {\pi} 4}^{2n\pi+\frac {3\pi} 4} \frac {e^{x}} {e^{x}+1}dx =\infty$ by showing that $\frac {e^{x}} {e^{x}+1}$ also has $\frac 1 2$ as lower bound on these intervals.